# Why is this a smooth manifold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, differential-topology, positive-semidefinite

I read that the space of quantum states, i.e. the space of density operators

$\mathcal{S}_n = \{ \rho \in H_n : \rho \geq 0, \, \, Tr[\rho]=1\}$

is a smooth manifold of dimension $n^2-1$, without further explanation. Could anyone help me understand why this is the case?

Here $H_n$ denotes the space of hermitian matrices: $H_n = \{ A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n} : \, A^* =A  \}$, and $\rho \geq 0$ means that the matrix $\rho$ is positive semi-definite.

Comment: Maybe try using the regular value theorem.

Comment: In principle, any subset of $\mathbb{C}^N$ defined by a systems of linear equations is a smooth submanifold, which can be checked directly by the definition. The same goes for strict linear inequalities. The one non-trivial thing here is the non-strict inequality $\rho \ge 0$, which may cause $\mathcal{S}_n$ to have boundary.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz that is exactly what I was trying to figure out. What's the impact of $\rho \geq 0$ in here? ...

Comment: This question has been [asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/277034/manifold-of-density-matrices), and it seems that $\mathcal{S}_n$ is in fact not a manifold. The exception is $\mathcal{S}_2$, which is diffeomorphic to the closed unit ball.

Comment: I suggest, you add a reference and the exact quote of the claim that this space is a smooth manifold (which is false).

Answer (score 1):

This is false, since the set has a boundary, but is not a even a manifold with boundary, since the boundary (the set of singular matrices with trace equal to one) is very singular. However, the set of **positive definite** hermitian matrices with trace equal to one is, indeed, an open manifold.

Answer (score -1):

[Preimage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem):

> Theorem. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a smooth map, and let $y\in Y$ be a regular value of $f$. Then $f^{-1}(y)$ is a submanifold of $X$. If $y\in {\text{im}}(f)$, then the codimension of $f^{-1}(y)$ is equal to the dimension of $Y$. Also, the tangent space of $f^{-1}(y)$ at $x$ is equal to $\ker(df_{x})$.